# React - How to access variable assigned in componentdidmount in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to pull in an object from Window and want to use it while rendering.

I am getting the value of comeponentData as undefined in console. How can I access the value?

```
class MobileBanner extends React.PureComponent {

componentDidMount(){
let banner = window.something.banner
this.setState({
  componentData: banner
})
}

render () {
const componentData =
  typeof dhome === 'undefined' || isEmpty(dhome)
    ? 'undefined'
    : this.state.componentData
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a default in the constructor.

```
class MobileBanner extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      componentData: ''
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
  let banner = window.something.banner
  this.setState({
    componentData: banner
  })
}

render () {
  const componentData =
    typeof dhome === 'undefined' || isEmpty(dhome)
      ? 'undefined'
      : this.state.componentData
  }
}
```

Learn more about *costructor* 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor